# CSS use :not ID with CLASS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Does someone know how to use the CSS selector `:not()` as `#some_id:not(.any_class_name)`?

The code looks as if it is right, but it doesn't work. Is there another way  without the `not` selector? I couldn't find anything on the Internet.

I am making a web application, which includes more than one page, but several pages have divs with `id=some_id`. I thought I had to add specific CSS by adding `any_class_name` one time using the above CSS code solve the problem, but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Comment: Could you provide an example of the selector not working? It would be better if you also create a JSFiddle.

Comment: Id's should only be occuring *once* per page. Multiple elements that share the same ID results in invalid HTML.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel better avoid w3schools references, better use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: Need to see your HTML, we have no knowledge of that to speak of.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel i already saw the link, here answer was written about .net

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich ok well it does work... did you see the note that it is not supported by IE <= 8?

Comment: @JustusRomijn a unique element with a unique ID may or may not have the given CSS class (eg #secondMenuItem.selected, #inputPassword.error) — the question isn't a contradiction of the unique ID principle.

Comment: @JustusRomijn i have read several time your link, but it doesn't help me, maybe I could not understand fully

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich can you provide some `HTML Markup` showing what you are trying to achieve and also what browsers you are targeting??

Comment: Thanks for all. It works, I made syntactic mistake

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I believe that you are *reversing* the selectors. You have some elements with the same `class`, but you want to filter out an element with an specific `ID`. In that case:

HTML:

```
<p class="someclass">hello</p> <!-- will be targeted by css below, thus green -->
<p class="someclass" id="some-id">hi</p> <!-- will not be targeted by css below -->
```

CSS:

```
.someclass:not(#some-id){ color: green; } 
/* selects all elements with classname 'someclass', 
   but excludes the one that has also has an id of 'some-id' */
```

And as @secretSquirrel pointed out, note the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility): this selector is not supported by Internet Explorer 8 and older.

Comment: Where does the question imply that there is more than one element with the same ID?

Comment: How can we use id more than once?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn ow, I thought because the OP asked an example with the id selector being filtered, there must be multiple elements on the same page that share an id, because why would you need the `:not` selector if there is only one element selected?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I misread the OP, I've updated my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This will set all the backgrounds except the ones that has `<a></a>`:

```
:not(a)
{
     background: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I  hope this will help you.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tripad/pQZkL/)

Another way is:
You can override the css. May be you want something like this.

```
<div id="demo">
<p class="class">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Your css

```
#demo
{
color:#0000ff;
}
.class
{
color:#ff0000;
}
```