# How to use CSS selector partial match with :not operator

Tags: html, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I want to get `Nokogiri` element that doesn't contain a specific string.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div id="foo"></div><div id="bar"></div>')
doc.css('*[id*="foo"]')
# => <div id="foo"/>
doc.css('*:not[id*="foo"]')
# => []
```

I thought `*:not[id*="foo"]` returns the element that has an id `bar`, but it doesn't.

How can I use partial match and `:not` operator at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) and here's a corresponding answer: "[CSS use :not ID with CLASS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20328803/6419007)" :

```
doc.css('div:not(#foo)')
```

will give you all the divs whose `id` isn't `foo`.

```
doc.css('*:not(#foo)')
```

will give you all the nodes whose `id` isn't `foo`.

```
doc.css('div:not([id*="foo"])')
```

will give you all the divs whose `id` doesn't contain `foo`.

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div id="foo"></div><div id="bar"></div><div id="foofoo"></div>')

puts doc.css('div:not([id*="foo"])')
#=> <div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some brackets in the negative condition. Use `:not(whatever)`

```
doc.css('*[id*="foo"]') # All elements with foo contained in the id

doc.css('*:not([id*="foo"])') # All elements without foo contained in the id
```