# CSS Global change to all UL LI except specific id or class

Tags: css

This is my first time posting here, so please go easy on me.

The following adds line height, removes the default bullet point and adds a symbol before all list items in the body of the stylesheet.

NOTE: I use Beaver Builder page plugin for wordpress. "fl-page-content" class excludes the header and the footer as i do not want the menus in them being affected.

```
ul {
  list-style: none; 
} 

.fl-page-content ul li:before { 
  content: ">\00a0" ;
  line-height:2; 
}
```

I have found 1 list where i do not want the above changes to take effect though. I have added a class "Missing" to this list and am trying to exclude it using the "not" property.

```
ul {
  list-style: none; 
} 

.fl-page-content:not(.
Missing) ul li:before{ 
  content: ">\00a0" ;
  line-height:2; 
}
```

It accepts the syntax but the list in question is still using the added symbol and line height.

Would really appreciate some advice on this. 
Many thanks

Comment: The list that should be exempted: Is it using a class or ID `Missing`? Your title says ID, but the question says class.

Comment: Try this if you added missing class on ul          .fl-page-content ul:not(.Missing) li:before

Comment: Sorry, "Missing" is an id, not a class. @Sirko

Comment: I just tried @NanditaAroraSharma suggestion

.fl-page-content ul:not(#Missing) li:before { 
  content: ">\00a0" ;
  line-height:2; 
} 

but it still styles the the list i need excluded.

Comment: please post your html if possible to help you better

Comment: On which tag are you applying "Missing" id ?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Sorry, i use a page builder so it does the html behind the scenes. 

But below shows a generic list that is displaying correctly with my css:

http://avemaria.ascet.co/dr-test/

Below shows the specific list on my 404 page layout, this is the list i do not want my custom css to take effect:

http://avemaria.ascet.co/sthsthsre

Comment: "Missing" id is applied to the module ( i use page builder) showing the list on my 404 page layout  http://avemaria.ascet.co/sthsthsre

Comment: Try this .fl-module.fl-module-menu:not(.Missing) ul li:before

Comment: I just applied that CSS. now the generic list has lost the styling

Comment: if `Missing` is an ID, use it as `.fl-page-content:not(#Missing) ul li:before`. the `.` is for classes, IDs are selected with `#` before the name. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20328803/3965832

Comment: And it would be much better to answer the question if you could post a [codepen](https://codepen.io) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) 

Comment: Try this .fl-page-content .fl-module.fl-module-menu:not(.Missing) ul li:before

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Still not working i am afraid, thanks for all your help so far though :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this exemple before in the morning, hope this can help you

```
div:not(.missing) ul.group li {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```
<body class="page">

<div class="missing">
  <ul class="group">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="page-section">
  <ul class="group">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

[>here<](https://jsfiddle.net/bwucpebw/) is a JSFiddle I made for you to try it

Comment: thank you. However, what i do not understand is how to i apply the "group" class to all  ULs like that? sorry, due to using the page builder in wordpress i don't actually write the html, just the css that tweaks it

Comment: Your welcome, the "group" class is applied using the "ul.group li" This mean all "li" which are contained into "ul" and thoses "ul" must have the "group"  class (more simply in css: "ul.group li"
Do not hesitate to ask me if you have any more questions

Comment: thanks for your help. sorry for not replying i have been a bit pre-occupied with another issue. I will try this within 48 hours and reply.